# Exclude Raster Cells with Value of Zero in ArcGIS 10.2 Raster Calculator Expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator

I need to perform a simple calculation in ArcGIS 10.1 Raster Calculator. I am using a raster layer that contains many cells that have a value of zero. I need to exclude these cells in the expression because they are skewing the results.

Here is the simple raster calculator expression that I am using:
"rho"* 1005*(((("raster")*.02)-272.15)-"temp")/30)

I need to add to this expression so that only values greater than zero in the raster layer "raster" are consider in the expression.

Comment: Generate Exclude Area (Data Management) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Generate_Exclude_Area/0017000000sz000000/ should be able to remove zero values or exclude from other raster processing

Comment: You may use "con" to ignore nodata value to process e.g. Con(<condition>, <true_expression>, <false_expression>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting your Zero values to NULL or "NODATA". Then as I have understood it, NODATA values will not get processed. You can use the [SetNull](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000007000000.htm) tool.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I used the expression: SetNull("raster" == 0, "raster") in the raster calculator, and it created a new raster layer of the cells that had values.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you should tick it as answered. This tells people who come looking with similar questions that a solution was given.