# Storm Total Precip Map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, precipitation

I'm using ArcMap 10.5.

I have two individual days of precip data rasters from NOAA/NWS.

I want to combine the two days with the cumulative total storm precip displayed in a new raster.

Many of the cells contain no data, and display as a value of -10000.

I've tried the raster calculator but the missing data cells cause a strange display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your NoData cells actually contain the value -10'000 and therefore produce said "strange values". So you need to tell the Raster Calculator to ignore these values. You can do this using SetNull (see [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129779/exclude-raster-cells-with-value-of-zero-in-arcgis-10-2-raster-calculator-express)), as the expression below shows:

```
SetNull("raster1" == -10000, "raster1") + SetNull("raster2" == -10000, "raster2")
```

This will change the -10'000 to actual NoData values in your raster before processing.